# Angular 6 should i create separate app or separate module for admin dashboard?

Tags: angular, module, angular6, project-structure, angular-module

I am currently working on a **angular 6** project to create a website  ( a company website ) with following features

1. Website which act as a company website + Online Store  with
   landing pages where contents (like slider, text and images, list) 
   can be changed from admin dashboard.
2. Also there is a products page with shopping cart where users can
   purchase company products by login in
3. Admin Dashboard where admin can control the contents in the
   website

**Note :**

Admin dashboard and  contents  of website ( expect the product pages and shopping card ) is connected to a NodeJs Api   website-api

Products listing and shopping cart is connected to different NodeJs Api

Presently i have created an angular project with following modules

- Admin Modules : with components and routes  related to admin dashboard
- Views Modules : with different components and routes related to different pages like home,about,contact us,careers etc
- Product Modules : with components related to product page , listing and shopping cart
- shared Module : With  components which are shared between these different modules

**Currently i have the following concerns :**

- How should i handle the project structure / modules to optimise it for performance ?
- How should i handle authentication since i have the same app connected to two separate API ( should i have separate authentication ) ?
- Should i create a separate angular 6 app for admin dashboard or should i stick with creating a different module in the same app ?

I appreciate any form of suggestion to improve the overall  app performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Performance

First, you should optimize your own code : avoid `O(n²)` complexity (or more), request only the required HTTP data, don't import modules you don't use ...

After that, you can also use lazy loading to load your modules on demand.

Finally, you can use Server Side Rendering to optimize the loading time of your application.

Splitting your app in two is of course going to impact your performance, but it highly depends on the content of both applications.

#### Authentication

It's up to you : you can either have two separate apps, with two separate databases and two different authentications, or you can have a single application with a role-based database.

I've seen and worked on both, neither is the best nor the worst. They both have advantages and drawbacks : it's up to you to choose.

Given those two opinions, you must guess the last : you can choose either way for your application. It really depends on you, your team, and your end users.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that first of all, each and every project should be approached according to its needs, scale, and complexity level.
With that said, in your specific case, I do think you should ask yourself, how big will that Admin Panel be?
I've seen, from admin panels, that's been minimal and narrow, just allowing the admin to perform simple admin-level actions, to full-scale admin panels, being used by hundreds, with different access levels, displaying statistical data on multi-screens in an operational room with 50 employees or more.
If you're admin panel should only perform basic to moderate complexity admin actions, it can be in the same app. If the scale and complexity gets bigger than that, you may consider separating it to a dedicated app, to maintain better control over the system.

Don't forget, separating to two apps, where it is not needed (small scale usually), will be likely to cause extra unwanted "mess".

The "scaling levels" mentioned in my answer, are all relational, as everything is.
So the one to make the call, and of course to "measure" things according to what the bigger picture looks like, is you.

Good luck!